# Is there a one-line "dot product" between a numpy 1D array and an array whose entries are matrices?

Tags: python, numpy

I want a simple way to get the "dot product" between a vector **r = [ r[1], r[2], r[3] ]** and an array **A = [ A[0], A[1], A[2] ]**, with the A[i]'s being matrices,  resulting in

`dot(r, A)  = r[0]*A[0] + r[1]*A[1] + r[2]*A[2]`

where **dot(r, A)** is a matrix. For example, **r** might be a numpy 1D array and **A** a numpy ndarray.

Comment: See `numpy.dot` (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)

Comment: @PabloC Yes, I've read it, but I don't see there a concrete example regarding my question.

Comment: Please give a concrete example of what is expected to be in `r` and `A` and what is expected output using code.

Comment: basically, a [mcve]

Comment: @DaniolF As I wrote above "dot(r, A)" is a matrix

Comment: And that's not at all clear what you mean, which is why I'm asking.  Use code.  Make a program that builds example inputs, and show *exactly* what output you want for that input.  Bonus if you have some code that gets you close to what you want.  We can't read minds.

Comment: Well, thanks anyway, the answer from @Melo is what I was looking for, he understood, but I'll try to write more clearly next time and put a concrete code.

Comment: Are you sure @Melo understood?  You had to add some sort of sum, didn't you?  Any ways, `r.dot(A)` produces the same thing as `sum([i*j for i,j in zip(r,A)])`.  (that's for a 1d `r` and 2d `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work?

```
>>> A
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> r
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> (A.T * r).T
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 8, 10, 12],
       [21, 24, 27]])
```

First row of `A` is multiplied by first element of `r`, second row by second element and so on and so forth. Just Transpose the Matrix and transpose the final result.

**Beware** - computationally expensive for big matrices.

Comment: This helps. But in you're example the result should be a vector: the sum of the rows.  Thanks!!

Comment: You don't need the tranposes if `r` is (3,1) shaped: `A*r[:,None]`